# Manually assign an IP

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router

I am trying to manually alter my `/etc/network/interfaces` file in `Ubuntu.`  I am using these as a baseline:

> ### To configure a dynamic IP address
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> ### Or configure a static IP
>
> auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet static
>     address 192.168.1.14
>     gateway 192.168.1.1
>     netmask 255.255.255.0
>     network 192.168.1.0
>     broadcast 192.168.1.255

Then once all settings have been entered and saved run this

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

I want to alter my wireless card, which according to ifconfig is **NOT** `eth0` but `wlp16s0` so the 1st thing I would do is change that.  My only question is what value would I input in `broadcast`

I know that the `address` is the IP I want to hardcode, `gateway` is my router IP, `netmask` is my DNS, `network` is my router IP

What for `Broadcast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Broadcast` address would be the highest non-assignable address for your subnet. It determines the end point of your network, where the `network` is the start point.

For example, with the following set up:

```
IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Network : 192.168.0.0
```

We have the We are using a network of 192.168.0.0 (Which is unassignable to one specific client) with the subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 (allowing addresses from 192.168.0.1 up to 192.168.0.254). This means our broadcast address will be

```
192.168.0.255
```

As this is one address higher than the highest assignable within the range.

---

Please note as well that your definitions aren't correct with this statement:

> I know that the address is the IP I want to hardcode, gateway is my router IP, netmask is my DNS, network is my router IP

The address is indeed the manually configured IP address for the client and the gateway, in most cases, would be your routers IP address. However, the netmask is *not* related to DNS in any way, but defines the range of IP addresses available within your subnet. You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork). Also note that the `network` address is defining the start point of the network, *not* your routers IP address. This should be the opposite of the broadcast address, the IP address *before* the first assignable address.

---

In all honesty, I don't think it would harm to leave these unset (although I haven't tested this as I don't have a UNIX system to test with). They're usually just for reference and can be automatically worked out from the host IP address and subnet mask.

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast address of an IPv4 network is the last address in the network.

[This answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) in [Network Engineering SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) discusses IPv4 addressing, and you can use it to figure out the various pieces, including the broadcast address.